# Is there any way to magnify the figures in the "Show" command?

Tags: plotting, graphics, magnification

I am trying to magnify a small part in the following Mathematica figure. What should I write in the 'show' environment to magnify the specific part of the figure?

```
Show[
   {U1, K1, B21, B31}
   , FrameLabel -> {"t", "S"}
   , PlotRange -> All
   , ImageSize -> Large
]
```

Where

```
U1 = ListLinePlot[
    Table[
        {(i) h, S[i]}
        , {i, 0, NN}
     ]
     , Joined -> True
     , PlotRange -> All
]
```

and similarly K1, B21, B31.

Your help would be highly appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. Please add a minimal example that forum participants can copy and paste to their notebook environments to replicate the errors or difficulties that you face. The comments and answers will consequently be more focused.

Comment: You could use `PlotRange -> {{xmin, xmax}, {ymin, ymax}}` in the `Show` command to show a specific part of the whole plot.